# How to align an image to the center with css?

Tags: css, alignment

I have three images. The need to be aligned so they fit on the same line and are centered. I have managed to align the 1st and 3rd image using float: left; and float: right; but I'm struggling to align the center image.

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94786808/example.png]

Here's the involved code:

```
.postprojects {
     margin-top: 60px;
     padding-left: 35px;
     padding-right: 35px;
     padding-top: 35px;
     background-image:url('image/bgprojects.png');
     width: 889px;
     height: 300px;
     }

.postproject1 {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.postproject2 {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.postproject3 {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any suggestions?

(P.S. Disregard the weird clipping on the bottom of the site. It's a padding error)

Comment: Can you provide us with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a demo live link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eFK7F/1/

Comment: Any ideas? by the way I've tried Margin-left/right: auto;. also text-align: center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, may be:

```
.postproject2 {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 73px 10px 0;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/eFK7F/2/

Comment: Welcome! :) Glad to have helped. :)